# /Applications/exec.c:2: error: include file 'stdio.h' not found

Tags: c

So I was going to start learning c when I saw:

```
/Applications/exec.c:2: error: include file 'stdio.h' not found
```

and my code was

```c
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{ 
    // Displays the string inside quotations
    printf("C Programming");
    return 0;
}
```

. Idk why I got that error and I'm panicking.

edit:
I was using tcc -run to try to make a mac executable in c and I decided to run it before turning to executable by adding #!/path/to/tcc/command
I tried:
Reinstalling tcc.
Edit 2:
I can move files over to /Applications and able to compile c programs.
But when I use tcc -run it interprets the file and I don't know if the program was messing something up.

Comment: What compiler are you using? This is not a runtime error btw.

Comment: Your installation is not complete.  What directions are you following?

Comment: `/Applications` suggests a Mac, but you should not be putting stuff such as `exec.c`  in there — it should only contain actual applications from `.pkg` or `.dmg` files. You shouldn't be able to put stuff in there, even. Either the permissions on the directory are damaged or you're running as `root` which is a silly thing to do. It looks as though you've not got XCode installed correctly, and/or the command line tools are not installed, and/or you have a compiler that expects the system headers to be in `/usr/include` whereas modern versions of XCode hide them in obscure, out-of-the-way places.